# javasript вопрос по регулярному выражению

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * Класс для работы с API
 *
 * @author      User Name
 * @version     v.1.0 (dd/mm/yyyy)
 */
class Api {
  constructor() {}

  /**
   * Заполняет строковый шаблон template данными из объекта object
   *
   * @author      User Name
   * @version     v.1.0 (dd/mm/yyyy)
   * @param       {object} object
   * @param       {string} template
   * @return      {string}
   */
  

    get_api_path(object, template) {
        let result = '';
    
        const replaced = api_path_templates.map((item) => {
          return item.replace(/%(\w+)%/g, (_, str) => {
            if (user[str]) {
              return encodeURIComponent(user[str]);
            } else {
              return str;
            }
          });
        });
    
        console.log(replaced);
    
        return result;
      }
    }
    
    let user = {
      id: 20,
      name: 'John Dow',
      role: 'QA',
      salary: 100,
    };
    
    let api_path_templates = [
      '/api/items/%id%/%name%',
      '/api/items/%id%/%role%',
      '/api/items/%id%/%salary%',
    ];
    
    let api = new Api();
    
    let api_paths = api_path_templates.map((api_path_template) => {
      return api.get_api_path(user, api_path_template);
    });
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(api_paths));

// Ожидаемый результат
let expected_result = [
  '/api/items/20/John%20Dow',
  '/api/items/20/QA',
  '/api/items/20/100',
];
```

Comment: в чем вопрос-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
let api_path_templates =
  [
      "/api/items/%id%/%name%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%role%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%salary%"
  ];

let user =
  {
      id      : 20,
      name    : 'John Dow',
      role    : 'QA',
      salary  : 100
  };

function get_api_path(object, template) {
    const replaced = template.map((item) => {
      return item.replace(/%(\w+)%/g, (_, str) => {
        if (object[str]) {
          return encodeURIComponent(object[str]);
        } else {
          return str;
        }
      });
    });
    return replaced;
}

const expected_result = get_api_path(user, api_path_templates);

console.log(expected_result);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо), а не подскажите, есть ли попроще решение? Это не совсем понятно в реализации=((((

Comment: К сожалению, я проще выдумать не могу, может, кто-то ещё подскажет. А что вызывает трудность? Если использование функции в качестве замены, можно почитать подробности [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) или [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-methods#str-replace-str-regexp-str-func). Если что-то другое не ясно, можно уточнить)

Comment: У меня просто по тз должен быть такой результат:   // Ожидаемый результат
  let expected_result = ["/api/items/20/John%20Dow","/api/items/20/QA","/api/items/20/100"]; Не понимаю в чем логика, но между John и Dow почему то береться %20

Comment: в Вашем варианте с map вообще нет ретерна( не могу понять, как он работает

Comment: У меня это строка повторяется все 3 раза (3) ["/api/items/20/John Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"]
1.js:38 (3) ["/api/items/20/John Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"]
1.js:38 (3) ["/api/items/20/John Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"]

Comment: Скорее всего `%20` — это от использования [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) — я добавил в ответ.

Comment: По поводу функций без returrn — загляните в варианты синтаксиса стрелочных функций (это сокращённый вариант с подразумеваемым return): https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics

Comment: Поменял имя переменной на expected_result, чтобы было яснее, как получить нужный результат.

Comment: Большое спасибо) Сейчас буду разбираться со всей инфой) Последний вопрос только) Подскажите пож. почему у Вас вызывается 1 раз, а у меня 3 раза.(3) ["/api/items/20/John%20Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"]
1.js:28 (3) ["/api/items/20/John%20Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"]
1.js:28 (3) ["/api/items/20/John%20Dow", "/api/items/20/QA", "/api/items/20/100"] Хотя использую все там же в map, цикла тут нет

Comment: @salco2012 А вы добавьте свой конечный вариант кода в конец своего вопроса, посмотрим, что там может быть не так)

Comment: Исправил код и обновил, готово+

Comment: @salco2012 Не уверен, как вы запускаете и проверяете код, но я вставил в свой ответ ваш вариант с некоторыми исправлениями, чтобы было яснее, как лучше использовать функцию с аргументами и выводить результат.

Comment: object и user используются вперемешку, хотя не должны.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо, исправил, это артефакты постоянного редактирования)